# PostMessage does not trigger Message Handler

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have a VC++ code that uses PostMessage to trigger a function call. Although the function gets called eventually, I see that the function does not get called right after PostMessage is executed. It does not even get called after the function containing the PostMessage command completes execution. I noticed that a few more functions got called before the desired function was called.

I would like to know what determines when exactly the callback for a message gets called.

The message is a WM_USER message.

Comment: PostMessage is asynchronous, this behavior is by definition. If you want synchronous call, use SendMessage. Generally, message handler is called when main application thread is activated, and handles all messages waiting in the queue.

Comment: Any clues then regarding why is the function not being called right away? It only gets called after a long time. It has messed up my flow, since I need the function to get called before some of the other stuff executes.

Comment: Which message are you sending? And are you certain that the target message handler is idle enough to get to your message?

Comment: If you call PostMessage from the main thread, it doesn't start until current message handler is executed.

Comment: See [About Messages and Message Queues - Message Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#routing) to learn about the difference between *Queued Messages* and *Nonqueued Messages*.

Comment: @tenfour I am sending a WM_USER message.

Comment: @user3112234: Are you sure?  Because it sounds like you are *posting* it, not *sending* it.

Comment: @BenVoigt, my bad. Yes, I am posting, not sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Windows event-driven model in a nutshell (with many important details simplified away):**

There is a "message pump," which is a loop that, on each iteration, pulls a message out of a queue and "dispatches" it by calling the "window procedure" associated with the specific window, passing it the details from the message.

If you're using a framework, it's likely that the message pump and the window procedure are provided for you and that the provided window procedure calls your handler functions in response to the messages it receives.

When a message is *posted*, it's added to the queue, and nothing else happens to it until the message pump gets to it.  There may be messages ahead of it in the queue, and/or a bunch of other code may run before execution returns to the message pump.

When a message is *sent*, the message is not added to the queue.  Instead, the sending code will call the window procedure directly.  (Caveat: this is an oversimplification.  Things are more complicated when sending a message to another thread.)

So if other functions are being called before the one you expect from your posted message, here are some possibilities:

1. Other messages were already in the queue when you posted your message.
2. Other messages are being sent rather than posted, so they're handled immediately, and only when they're done and the message pump eventually runs again will your posted message be handled.
3. The message pump decided that other messages, which were posted after yours, are more important and therefore should be handled first.  (This is not actually common.  Certain types of messages, like WM_PAINT, are very low priority and are only generated when there's nothing in the queue, but I can't think of a case where a message takes priority over one that's already in the queue.)
4. You're posting your message during initialization before the message pump even starts.  For example, if you create a window, post a message to it, and then start the message pump, it's possible that there will be a series of messages in the queue related to the window creation ahead of your posted message.

Comment: "When a message is sent, the message is not added to the queue. Instead, the sending code will call the window procedure directly."  Only true when calling `SendMessage` from the thread that owns the window.  Otherwise, when `GetMessage` (or similar `PeekMessage`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`) is called from the thread that does own the window, it will call the window procedure, before returning with the next dequeued posted message.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I thought my bold disclaimer was enough.  There are lots of details like this that make what I wrote not quite true.  I believe, however, that the OP just needs some of the basics to understand the behavior described.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to leave out details. For example you could say "when a message is sent from the UI thread. ..." and never describe the cross thread behavior. Simplifying to the point where it is wrong is, in my opinion, worse than explicitly not covering some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Not all messages are equal. `PostMessage` doesn't simply add it to a queue data structure; the OS will do a lot of manipulation and prioritizing. Different messages get different priorities, and some messages like `WM_PAINT`, cannot be sent like this at all.

So there's no way to generalize "when will `PostMessage` invoke the message handler?" It depends on which message you're sending, how busy the target message queue is, and how the target message loop behaves.

I don't think there is any concise list of how messages are prioritized.